# Error in executing dynamic sql query with datetime variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Table creation : (tbl1 & tbl2)

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1
( 
    EmpID               int         , 
    EmpName             varchar(20)     , 
    Experience                    int           ,
    Roll                varchar(30)     ,
    DOJ             datetime                  ,
    PRIMARY KEY(EmpID,DOJ)    
); 

CREATE TABLE tbl2
( 
    ProjID              int     ,
    ProjName                      varchar(40)   , 
    ProjDuration                int     ,
    EmpID               int     ,
    DOJ             datetime              ,
    PRIMARY KEY(ProjName,EmpID,DOJ)
);
```

tbl1 Values :

```
   EmpID        EmpName           Experience        Roll       DOJ

11  aaa     NULL        PAT 2013-11-22 00:00:00.000
22  bbb     2       PA  2012-05-16 00:00:00.000
33  eee     NULL        A   2008-12-10 00:00:00.000
44  NULL        3       NULL    2011-06-26 00:00:00.000
55  ddd     NULL        NULL    2010-08-12 00:00:00.000
66  ccc     1       NULL    2013-05-02 00:00:00.000
77  NULL        NULL        SA  2006-12-01 00:00:00.000
```

tbl2 Values :

```
ProjID   ProjName        ProjDuration           EmpID       DOJ

NULL       3M       2       33  2008-12-10 00:00:00.000
2002       3M       NULL        55  2010-08-12 00:00:00.000
3003       MPC      3       11  2013-11-22 00:00:00.000
NULL       MPC      NULL        66  2013-05-02 00:00:00.000
3003       MPC      3       77  2006-12-01 00:00:00.000
1001       Shell              NULL      22  2012-05-16 00:00:00.000
1001       Shell              4     44  2011-06-26 00:00:00.000
```

Stored Procedure to retrieve the columns which are not null : (with EmpID and DOJ as parameters)

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Sample
    @EmpID                  INT     ,
    @DOJ                    DATETIME        
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @query nVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @T_EmpID nVARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @T_DOJ nVARCHAR(15)
SET @T_EmpID = convert(varchar(5), @EmpID);
SET @T_DOJ = convert(varchar(15), @DOJ);
SET @query = 'select '''+@T_EmpID+''' as EmployeeID';
IF((select EmpName from tbl1 where EmpID = @T_EmpID and DOJ = @T_DOJ) is not null)
    SET @query += ',EmpName';
IF((select Experience from tbl1 where EmpID = @T_EmpID and DOJ = @T_DOJ) is not null)
    SET @query += ',Experience';
IF((select Roll from tbl1 where EmpID = @T_EmpID and DOJ = @T_DOJ) is not null)
      SET @query += ',Roll';
IF((select ProjID from tbl2 where EmpID = @T_EmpID and DOJ = @T_DOJ) is not null)
    SET @query += ',ProjID';
IF((select ProjName from tbl2 where EmpID = @T_EmpID and DOJ = @T_DOJ) is not null)
    SET @query += ',ProjName';
IF((select ProjDuration from tbl2 where EmpID = @T_EmpID and DOJ = @T_DOJ) is not null)
    SET @query += ',ProjDuration';
SET @query += ' from tbl1 a join tbl2 b on a.EmpID = b.EmpID and a.DOJ = b.DOJ where a.EmpID = '+@T_EmpID+'and a.DOJ = '+@T_DOJ 

IF (@query IS NOT NULL)
Exec (@query)

END

EXEC sp_Sample '55','2010-08-12 00:00:00.000'
```

Error on executing the stored procedure :

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_Sample, Line 13

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can anyone please help me to solve this error ???
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add a `PRINT` before you execute your dynamic query to see what it actually looks like?

Comment: Of course it does, I wasn't giving a solution. But is the query formed  after your processing a valid query? Check if you have missing single quotes for the variables

Comment: yeah query is valid its working

Comment: Thank you Shree Patwardhan for responding to my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Stored procedure as following format:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_Sample
    @EmpID                  INT     ,
    @DOJ                    DATETIME        
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @query nVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @T_EmpID nVARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @T_DOJ nVARCHAR(15)
SET @T_EmpID = convert(varchar(5), @EmpID);
SET @T_DOJ = convert(varchar(15), @DOJ,111);
SET @query = 'select '''+@T_EmpID+''' as EmployeeID';
IF((select EmpName from tbl1 where EmpID = @T_EmpID and DOJ = @DOJ) is not null)
    SET @query += ',EmpName';
IF((select Experience from tbl1 where EmpID = @T_EmpID and DOJ = @DOJ) is not null)
    SET @query += ',Experience';
IF((select Roll from tbl1 where EmpID = @T_EmpID and DOJ = @DOJ) is not null)
      SET @query += ',Roll';
IF((select ProjID from tbl2 where EmpID = @T_EmpID and DOJ = @DOJ) is not null)
    SET @query += ',ProjID';
IF((select ProjName from tbl2 where EmpID = @T_EmpID and DOJ = @DOJ) is not null)
    SET @query += ',ProjName';
IF((select ProjDuration from tbl2 where EmpID = @T_EmpID and DOJ = @DOJ) is not null)
    SET @query += ',ProjDuration';
SET @query += ' from tbl1 a join tbl2 b on a.EmpID = b.EmpID and a.DOJ = b.DOJ where a.EmpID = '+@T_EmpID+'and a.DOJ = '''+@T_DOJ +''''

IF (@query IS NOT NULL)
Exec (@query)
END
GO

EXEC sp_Sample '55','2010-08-12 00:00:00.000'
```

My change is:

1. SET @T_DOJ = convert(varchar(15), @DOJ,111);
2. ... and DOJ = @DOJ (In all of where conditions)

Comment: Hi, its working fine.. Thank you.. I m beginner in dynamic sql queries.. Can u please explain me why it doesn't work with the previous where condition DOJ = @T_DOJ ???

Comment: The data type of DOJ column is `DateTime` but @T_DOJ data type is varchar(15) and format of converted data from datetime to varchar is not suitable.

Comment: Hi I'm trying to execute another procedure of similar type
In tis case, in both the tables i ve 1 column of same name.

Comment: so i've used like 

IF((select Doc_Work as PSU_Doc_Work from tblPSU where Employee_ID = (@)T_EmpID and Project_Name = (@)T_ProjName and Date_of_work = (@)Date) is not null)

    SET (@)query += ',PSU_Doc_Work';

IF((select Doc_Work as PC_Doc_Work from tblPC where Employee_ID = (@)T_EmpID and Project_Name = (@)T_ProjName and Date_of_work = (@)Date) is not null)
    SET (@)query += ',PC_Doc_Work';

Comment: but I m getting error as Ambiguous column name 'Doc_Work'

Comment: Can u please help me in this ?

Comment: You must use `TableName.Column` in select of your query. for example `tblPSU.Doc_Work` and `tblPC.Doc_Work`. this error raised when you have a column in more than one table (in joined query).

Comment: When I use that, I'm getting error as The multi-part identifier "tblPSU.Doc_Work" could not be bound.

Comment: @Prithy Raman. Please edit your question and add your stored procedure completely.

Comment: @mehdilotfi you may be wrong about that chief. He doesn't "have to" do anything. However it it solves the problem it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string into timestamp first and them compare/assign

Instead of

`DOJ = @T_DOJ`

Try

```
DOJ = to_TIMESTAMP(@T_DOJ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:FF')"
or 
DOJ = TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(@T_DOJ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:FF')"
```

Functions used above are for DB2. Use equivalent/compatible functions for DB server you are using.

Comment: Thank you Neeraj for responding to my query